# How does Google Analytics calculate time on page?

Tags: google-analytics

How is Time on Page calculated by GA?
Referring to the first search result link that appeared - https://help.analyticsedge.com/article/misunderstood-metrics-time-on-page-session-duration/

```
If Visitor 1 visited page1 at 0:00 and moved to page2 at 0:45, then 
time on page for page1 = 0:45-0:00 = 0:45
time on page for page2 = ???-0.45 = 0:00
Session duration = 0:45
```

If this was true then if a user spent 10 mins on a single page where he just read content but never went to other page then will the time on page and session duration be 0:00?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can only track time against another action. In most cases this means non-bounce and non-exit pages only have a time on page stat. There are other ways to get timer stats. If you use Google Tag Manager you can use a timer trigger to fire at intervals, so it will fire, for example,  every 10 seconds that someone is on the page, and not fire when they've left the page.